# add formatter for X-axis in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to show custom `Label` in `X-Axis` and add this code for some test:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
       style: {
       color: 'red',
       fontSize: 16
    },
    formatter: function() {
        return '<span style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold">' + this.value + '</span>';
    }
 }
}
```

but `Dates` does not shown correctly:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vLjrb3f/)

Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you add that piece of code in to your jsfiddle? Please add some comment by the code you import. Or add it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry I Update My Question

Comment: `return '<span style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold">' + this.value + '</span>';` you don not need to add the span tag the css is in the `style: {  color: 'red', fontSize: 16 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.value` is probably returning the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

To get the formatted date, use `Highcharts.dateFormat` with the specifier you want. For instance, day and month:

```
var date = Highcharts.dateFormat("%e %b", this.value)
```

For a complete list of specifiers, see here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1,
    inputBoxStyle: {
      right: '80px'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: 'red',
        fontSize: 16
      },
      formatter: function() {
       var date = Highcharts.dateFormat("%e %b", this.value)
        return '<span style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold">' + date + '</span>';
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'USD to EUR',
    data: usdeur
  }],

  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
      }
    }
  }
});

$('#button').click(function() {
  chart.exportChart();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<button id="button">Export chart</button>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```